# Linux shell script sqlite3: adjust column width

Tags: sqlite

I am managing a sqlite3 db with a shell script. I want to adjust the column width when I a call a select on the db to properly show the data. It is possible to add the -column and -header params when calling, but I have not found a possibility to add the column width. Right now my command looks like this:

```
sqlite3 -column -header $database "SELECT * FROM $table1;"
```

When using sqlite3 manually in the terminal, the command for adjusting the width is

```
.width x y z...
```

where x is the width of column1 and so on, which works fine. My current workaround to show data with a length of > ~20 chars (everything above is trimmed) is to set the column name to a something that has the desired length, which overwrites the default length. This however is not dynamic and does not look nice. Is there a possibility to directly change the column width when selecting the data? BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood what you want, you can specifify the displayed widths this way:

```
sqlite3 -column -header -cmd ".width $w1 $w2 ..." $database "SELECT * FROM $table1;"
```

But if this is part of a script, you can also do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
database="..."
table1="..."

sqlite3 "$database" <<EOF
.headers on
.mode column
.width $w1 $w2 ...
SELECT * FROM $table1;
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you, both works perfectly in a Script! I was not yet familiar with EOF. BR

Comment: Glad to have helped.